# cloned octopress repository doesn't let me push to github

Tags: git, github

I cloned the `octopress` repository.

I cloned it as a subdirectory into the project where I also use the octopress gem (for converting drafts into posts).

In order to automate my deploy (e.g. moving things from the _posts for the octopress gem into the octopress file for the rake generate command, I need to push everything into github.

But it treats everything in octopress as a submodule, so I get a fatal pathspec error.

**Question: how do I make the cloned directory appear, not as a submodule, but just as a regular subdirectory?**

Comment: Tried deleting the `.git` folder in the octopress folder?

Comment: Hi yes I did but I still got the problem.